# Giving two equal line segments AC and BD so that they bisect each other at E. Prove that quadrilateral ABCD is a Rectangle.

Tags: geometry

Given $AC=BD$

so 
$\angle AED= \angle CEB$ by Prop I.15

$AE+EC$ and $BE=DE$ by definition of bisect

So by $SAS$, $\triangle AED$ is congruent to $\triangle BEC$ (postulate 12)
Therefor $AD=BC$

Then by Prop I. 15 $\angle AEB= \angle CED$  and $\triangle BEA \cong \triangle CED$

so $CD=AB$.

$\angle EDA= \angle EBA$, by Prop I.34

so $BC\parallel AD$

$\angle EAB= \angle ECD$ by Prop. I.34

so $BA=CD$

But how do I prove that the angles are right angles?

Comment: $\angle AED$ is an exterior angle of $\triangle ABE$, and $\angle AEB$ is an exterior angle of $\triangle AED$. I think that, together with the fact that the three angles of a triangle sum to $180^{\circ}$, should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) A quadrangle is a parallelogram iff its diagonals bisect each other

2) A paralellogram is a rectangle iff its diagonal's lengths are equal

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

Let $M$ be he midpoint of $AD$. Since the triangles $\triangle(AEM)$ and $\triangle(DEM)$ have equal sides they are congruent. It follows that $\angle(AME)=\angle(DME)={\pi\over2}$, and that $E\vee M$ is an angle bisector at $E$.